# ¿Como obtener el contenido de un documento en especifico de firestore con angularfire?

Tags: angular, web, sql, google-cloud-firestore, visualización-de-datos

Estoy aprendiendo angular 9 con firestore. Lo que quiero es tomar los datos del documento de esta subcoleccion en específico,y guardar cada uno en una variable respectivamente. 
Para después mostrarla en pantalla.

La ruta es: consulta/uid/consultas/fecha

Ej:

D1 = contenido de d1

D2 = contenido de d2

D3 = contenido de d3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad soy bastante nuevo, así que no se que hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para poder traer datos específicos de un documento en firebase usando angularfire puedes usar la directiva `.doc()` de firestore:

```
  getConsultas(fecha) {
    return this.afs.collection('consultas').doc(fecha).valueChanges()
    }
```

Asi mismo puedes usar query filters con los que puedes filtrar que documentos quieres recivir, te dejo la docu aqui: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=es

Comment: Gracias, si lo he intentado así, pero mi duda es como almacenó el contenido en las variable d1, d2 y d3 ya que, así como me comentas es solo mostrar.

Comment: Para almacenarlas deberias crear tres variables y llamar a la funcion : this.getConsultas(fecha).subscribe((res: any) => { this.varibale1 = res.d1; this.variable2 = res.d2; this.variable3 = res.d3})

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a intentar, que la verdad, en gran parte de mis busquedas, los tutoriales, paginas, foros y demas solo dicen como obtener todo el contenido de todos los documentos y como mostrarlos, pero no como almacenarlos y yo solo quiero eso, obtener ese dato especifico y almacenarlo.

Comment: Es normal, no te preocupes que en cuento cojas practica con esto el resto sera automatico. Saludos

Comment: No me funciono, o no se que hacer exactamente xc.